# Checking for a matrix of if conditions in Swift 3 or 4

Tags: ios, swift, conditional-statements, control-flow

Let's say I have a matrix of conditions I need to check:

```
let one: String? = "one"
let two: String? = nil

func test() {
    if one == nil && two == nil {
        print("neither are valid")
    } else if one == nil {
        print("one is nil")
    } else if (two == nil) {
        print("two is nil")
    } else {
        print("\(one) and \(two) are valid")
    }
}
```

Is there a function of the Swift language that would enable me to write this more cleanly and "Swift-like"? Would that same syntax scale well to a three-dimensional set of conditions?

I know that using `guard`, I could check that both values are valid before I continue on, but then I need to perform certain actions based on whether one, both, or neither are nil, and **this would obviously result in some false positives (where guard expects both to be valid before continuing)**:

```
guard let one = one, let two = two else {
    return
}
if one == nil {
    print("one is nil")
} else if (two == nil) {
    print("two is nil")
} else {
    print("\(one) and \(two) are valid")
}
```

I'm sure I could use `switch` too, but that doesn't seem any more elegant than the endless if/else:

```
switch (one != nil || two != nil) {
case one == nil && two == nil:
    print("neither are valid")
case one == nil:
    print("one is nil")
case two == nil:
    print("two is nil")
default:
    print("\(one) and \(two) are valid")
}
```

Comment: Your first example is pretty Swift-like :) `Guard` statement you're using wrong.

Comment: Yep, I wrote that into the question already - I know it's wrong  Emboldened to draw unnecessary attention to its wrongness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Swift `switch` like this:

```
switch (one, two) {
case (nil, nil):
    print("neither are valid")
case (nil, _?):
    print("one is nil")
case (_?, nil):
    print("two is nil")
default:
    print("\(one) and \(two) are valid")
}
```

Comment: NOW we're talking! That looks pretty _swift_ ;)

Comment: This solution is amazing, Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't scale too well though. Try this when checking 4 or 5 values instead of 2. The question does ask about scale with more values.

Comment: It still scales better than if/else statements in nested { }. It visually reads like a matrix that you can clearly see where `nil` is in the conditions. Accepting this since it compiles and works for me, but I'll be happy to revisit if someone can do better!

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks. Your comment is so reasonable. But thinking a typical use case, we need 2^n `case`s for n-Optional values. Under that condition, this answer may not be too far, I think. And I also hope to see some better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did which I think is pretty swifty and scales to handle as many strings as you want:

```
let string1: String? = "A"
let string2: String? = "B"
let string3: String? = "C"

let validStrings = [string1, string2, string3].flatMap { $0 }

switch validStrings.count {
case 0:
    print("No valid strings")
case 1:
    print(validStrings[0] + " is valid")
case _:
    let comaSeparated = validStrings[0..<validStrings.count - 1].joined(separator: ", ")
    let lastValue = validStrings[validStrings.count - 1]
    print([comaSeparated, lastValue].joined(separator: " and ") + " are valid")
}
```

First you use `flatMap` to get an array with only non-nil strings, then use a switch and handle three cases: no valid strings, one valid string, two or more valid strings.

In the final case we use `joined()` twice to make it pretty to read.

In the end, if all strings are non-nil, like in the example, you'll get this:

```
A, B and C are valid
```

Feel free to paste it in a playground.

Comment: This definitely works for strings, but what if I was checking something like if an array of view controllers was nil? It's flexible in a sense, but also rigid in that non-strings aren't easily identifiable.

Comment: If you know what you're doing it's very easy to map your objects to a string with some useful information that would tell you more than "one is nil". It also doesn't become horrible code when you add one or more variables (like you mentioned in your question).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
enum TwoCondition<L, R> {
    case leftNil(R)
    case rightNil(L)
    case bothNil
    case passed(L, R)

    static func check(_ l: L?, _ r: R?) -> TwoCondition<L,R> {
        if let l = l, let r = r { return .passed(l, r) }
        if let l = l { return .rightNil(l) }
        if let r = r { return .leftNil(r) }
        return .bothNil
    }
}
```

Then you can check any optional values:

```
let one: String? = "one"
let two: String? = nil

switch TwoCondition.check(one, two) {
case .leftNil(let r):
    print("one is nil, two is: \(r)")
case .rightNil(let l):
    print("two is nil, one is: \(l)")
case .bothNil:
    print("neither are valid")
case .passed(let l, let r):
    print("\(l) and \(r) are valid")
}
```

As bonus, you'll have unwrapped values ;)

Comment: Like your functional approach!